# Some script ran when accidentally clicked on a fake notification window. iPhone 13 pro

Tags: iphone, safari, malware

I was using Safari on an iPhone 13 pro with the latest updates and stumbled upon an article in a website with a lot of ads and I accidentally touched on a fake window for notifications subscription that caused some type of script to be executed on my phone-really fast my phone started performing operations on its own - safari was minimized , phone "Settings" popped up , I got a glimpse and some type of "Subscription menu" at first, then I remember seeing the list of my email accounts and calendar options. After that I managed to click the back to safari button on the left top corner of the phone screen and the script execution stopped. How worried I should be and what steps should I perform now?